# Objective C: Gesture Issue

Tags: objective-c, ios, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

i set a UITapGesture on my scrollView but because of that i can't use the button inside my scrollView... all it reads is the action of the gesture for the scrollView.

how am i gonna able to fix that?

i have this code:

```
    UIGestureRecognizer *tapIt = [[ UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
    imgTap = (UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapIt;
    imgTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    imgTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    [scrollView addGestureRecognizer:imgTap];
```

Comment: What happens if you add that tap recognizer in your scrollview's contentView and not to the scrollview directly? Will that work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to prevent the touch from reaching the button in the gesture delegate:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch{
if ([touch.view isDescendantOfView:myButton]) {
    return NO;
}

return YES;
```

}

Comment: I'm kinda sure that it works, since I have used it. Are you sure you have set yourself as the delegate for the gesture recognizer?

Comment: thanks! it's working now! i forgot to set the delegate! you saved me!! today is my deadline hehe! thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can set cancelsTouchesInView property on your gesture to NO. Also there should be some method to ignore gestures in some parts of a view.